# How To return a Object constructed via JPA Repository Query with a Join

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

Let's say I have 2 tables- Order and OrderHistory. Order has a primary key but OrderHistory doesn't and I've added  a fake key for it for the below join.

The join is to get a resultset

```
@Query(value="SELECT H.order_Id, H.order_desc,H2.order_date from Order_HISTORY H join ORDER O on O.USER_ID=H.USER_ID join  (select order_id, min(order_date) from T_ORDER_HISTORY group by order_id) H2 on H1.order_id=H2.order_id where O.order_date=?1", nativeQuery=true)
```

Basically its mapped object that's using a select number of fields.

method call is as follows

```
List<OrderSimple> getHistoryById(Integer Id)
```

Right now its erroring out with a "could not resolve property order_id" message - I'm guessing because of the join query its not able to convert to OrderSimple. I tried adding onetoMany annotation to remove the "join on" condition but since it's  not a jpa managed relationship its throwing an error.
How can I return this object in this case? If you can point me to an example that would be great.

```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity(name="T_ORDER")
public class Order {
    @Id @Column(name="ORDER_ID")
    private Long orderId;
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Long userId;
    @Column(name="ORDER_DESC")
    private String orderDesc;
    @Column(name="ORDER_DATE")
    private Date orderDate;
    @Column(name="ORDER_DESC2")
    private String orderDesc2;
}

@Getter @Setter
@Entity(name="T_ORDER_HISTORY")
public class OrderHistory {
    @Id @Column(name="ROWID")
    private String id;
    @Column(name="ORDER_ID")
    private Long orderId;
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Long userId;
    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String orderDesc;
    @Column(name="ORDER_DATE")
    private Date orderDate;
    @Column(name="ORDER_DESC2")
    private String orderDesc2;
}

@Getter @Setter
public class OrderSimple {
    @Id @Column(name="ORDER_ID")
    private Long orderId;
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Long userId;
    @Column(name="ORDER_DESC")
    private String orderDesc;
    @Column(name="ORDER_DATE")
    private Date orderDate;
}
```